# Rails 5 - Forbidden Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

Rails is throwing an error when attempting to create when I have added all the attributes to the necessary function and referenced it in the right places (as far as I am aware). Can sucessfuly update. It is happening accross multiple controllers, unfortunately. I assume the problem is the same for all of them.

This is part of an upgrade to rails 5, previously rails 2. Ruby version: 2.6.3

Create function:

```
def create
    @shipment_method = ShipmentMethod.new(shipment_methods_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shipment_method.save
        format.html { redirect_to shipment_methods_url, notice: 'Shipment method was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @shipment_method, status: :created, location: @shipment_method }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @shipment_method.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Params function:

```
def shipment_methods_params
    params.require(:shipment_method).permit(:name, :description, :shipping_url, :active, :supports_tracking, :requires_phone)
  end
```

Request params:

```
Request parameters  
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KjPFsCA5xwgeIx4U3eOH4sA1IuYY5FSw6kvK16XyyKarEzlxSi6N04LFBdsJHWyIwt+ujv6gz9D+flYBeJ+pWA==", "shipment_method"=>{"name"=>"1", "description"=>"1", "shipping_url"=>"1", "active"=>"0", "supports_tracking"=>"0", "requires_phone"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Shipment method", "controller"=>"shipment_methods", "action"=>"create"}
```

Server log for the request:

```
Processing by ShipmentMethodsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KjPFsCA5xwgeIx4U3eOH4sA1IuYY5FSw6kvK16XyyKarEzlxSi6N04LFBdsJHWyIwt+ujv6gz9D+flYBeJ+pWA==", "shipment_method"=>{"name"=>"1", "description"=>"1", "shipping_url"=>"1", "active"=>"0", "supports_tracking"=>"0", "requires_phone"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Shipment method"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)



ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
```

Full class:

```
class ShipmentMethod < ActiveRecord::Base
  # public :description, :active, :name, :requires_phone, :supports_tracking, :shipping_url

  ## Associations
  has_many :shipments

  ## Validations
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  ## Scopes
  default_scope -> {order(:name)}
  scope :active, -> {where("active = 1")}
end
```

Comment: Can you post your ShipmentMethod class?  I see in the log that User model is loading with id 5, is this the current_user value?  Does ShipmentMethod have a dependency on User?  Is there a before_save or some other callback on the model here that touches User and validates something?  I suspect it might be related to some dependencies.

Comment: Posted the class- I believe that the user model loads that due to cancancan authorization for the page, but Ill look into it.

Comment: Sorry - I meant the ShipmentMethod model itself - not the controller.

Comment: Model posted, not sure what I was thinking! This is frying my poor brain.

Commenting out everything in the create method causes the same error, so I am searching elsewhere in the pipeline.

Comment: Are there any more details in the log after the `ForbiddenAttributesError:` line? I would expect there to be a couple more details that might help...

Comment: No, I just cleared it and ran it again to be sure. It is reporting everything (not just errors) so unfortunately no more details there.

Comment: Can you try 'params.permit' instead of 'params.require(:shipment_method).permit' and see if the object is created?

Comment: No change when I try removing the .require but, @dbugger there are no other definitions for the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a `load_and_authorize_resource` before action in your controllers, what is happening is that method is taking your parameters and attempting to create an instance before it ever gets to the method. Hence it ignores the strong parameters you have created.

So, of course, it never reaches the method and BAM -- the dreaded **FAE**.

One remedy is to tweak the before actions...

```
  load_and_authorize_resource :shipment_method, except: [:create]
  authorize_resource :shipment_method, only: [:create]
```

But that is very dull.

The other is to change the name of your strong parameters method to `shipment_method_params`...

```
def shipment_method_params
    params.require(:shipment_method).permit(:name, :description, :shipping_url, :active, :supports_tracking, :requires_phone)
  end
```

Because, Rails and its love of conventions. You can also make separate `create_params` and `update_params` if you have different parameters for those actions.